# Setting single bit Siemens ladder

Tags: plc, siemens, ladder-logic

I have a value stored in MW20 and I need to set to most significant bit to 0 without using bit operations but I don't find how I need to do this. I know this:

```
     ----> MB20 = D7
    /
MW20 = D7C5
    \
     ----> MB21 = C5
```

So I need to set the last bit of MB20 to 0. I thought this was going to be as easy of doing a move from 0 to M20.7 but no I get this error:

[image]

I don't understand that it is this hard to set an individual bit. I have searched far and wide but can't find a solution. As a reminder I cannot use bit operations and I'm use LADDER on Siemens PLC.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without using bit operations. Out of curiosity, why is a standard coil unavailable?

Comment: It is for a school assignment and I actually didn't think about just using the coil as out. This is just a little part of my education and just to give an intro to PLC programming and I'm not used to it. I was so focussed on the move part that I didn't think about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a standard coil tied to the bit in question.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use a coil like this

[image]

then you can use the appropriate logic to turn off (i.e.  equal to 0 ) or turn on (i.e. equal to 1).

Answer (score 0):

You could logically AND the MW20 register with 0x7FFF (that's 2#0111111111111111) to clear the most significant bit. I believe the Siemens instruction is WAND_W.